# seperate each individual matrix into a seperate file

Tags: lua

file.csv  which stored n matrices. For example,

```
   A  B  C
A  0  3  4
B  5  0  7
C  7  8  0

   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  4  5 
B  5  0  7  9
C  7  8  0  5
D  7  8  6  0
```

all the matrix separated by a blank line.

I wanna separate each individual matrix into a separate file (1.csv,2.csv...n.csv). Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Read the file line by line, if line `'^$'` then close the writefile and open a new one. Do you  need more detailed snippets?

Comment: What exactly is giving you difficulty in implementing this?

Comment: I am new to lua,  badly need more detailed sinppets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  Only the data part is saved in the CSV.  If you need the headers, you need to add some code in save_csv().  Example data in `data` string.  You could initialize `data` by loading to it whatever file you like.

```
data = [[

   A  B  C
A  0  3  4
B  5  0  7
C  7  8  0



   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  4  5
B  5  0  7  9
C  7  8  0  5
D  7  8  6  0


]]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local cc = table.concat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function save_csv(filenumber,t)
  io.open(filenumber .. '.csv','w'):write(cc(t,'\n')):close()
end
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local filenumber = 1
local ans = {}

for line in (data..'\n'):gmatch '(.-)\n' do
  local s = {}
  for item in line:gmatch '%d+' do s[#s+1] = item end
  if #s > 0 then
    ans[#ans+1] = cc(s,',')
  elseif #ans > 0 then
    save_csv(filenumber,ans)
    filenumber = filenumber + 1
    ans = {}
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer is cool. However, can you tell me how to save the headed in the file, and how to read data from csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly, this should exactly do what you want.

Quick and dirty

```lua
-- read lines
local files, data = {}
for line in io.lines('file.csv') do
  if (line == '') then
    if data then table.insert(files, data) end
    data = nil
  else
    data = (data and (data .. '\n') or '') .. line
  end
end

-- last file
if data then table.insert(files, data) end

-- write files
for i = 1, #files do
  local f = io.open(i .. '.csv', 'w')
  f:write(files[i])
  io.close(f)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but how can I compile and run those code in windows, I am a rookie to LUA.

Comment: Hi, csaar, thanks for your help, but it seems doesn't work. Everything has written in only one file: 1.csv.

Comment: If it saves all in one file, the condition fails. So check your linebreak lines for spaces or other empty characters, be a bit more proactive..
You could change the condition to `if (string.match(data, '^%s*$')) then` or similar. Try it!;)